# Use local variable in template html without component Angular2+

Tags: html, angular

I want to use a local variable into my html template to use it in css classes but without linking it with the component. I want to do that :

```
[local_html_variable = 1]

    <div class="css-{{ local_html_variable }}">
            Div #1
        </div>

[local_html_variable + 1]

        <div class="css-{{ local_html_variable }}">
            Div #2
        </div>

[local_html_variable + 1]

        <div class="css-{{ local_html_variable }}">
            Div #3
        </div>

        ...
```

to get

```
<div class="css-1">
        Div #1
    </div>

    <div class="css-2">
        Div #2
    </div>

    <div class="css-3">
        Div #3
    </div>

    ...
```

Important : the number of div is dynamic.
But I don't achieve it. I tried with `<ng-template let-localHtmlVariable>` but didn't work.. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *ngFor structural directive

```
<div *ngFor="let value of [1,2,3]" class="css-{{value}}">
   DIV #{{value}}
</div>
```

Comment: In fact I can't use ngFor in my case

Comment: @MatDepInfo, please consider adding all the relevant details and conditions upfront, so as to avoid additional noise to the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very situational answer that takes advantages of truhy/falsy values :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="1 as i">
  Number is {{ i }}
</ng-container>
```

Use it in your classes in the container itself :

```
<div class="css-{{ i }}">With interpolation</div>
<div [class]="'css-' +  i">With input</div>
```

Here is the stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3wm4en?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**EDIT** explanation :

In javascript, every value can be transalted to boolean : they are truthy or falsy values.

The quick boolean parse operator is the `!!` double negation.

Let's try :

```js
console.log(!!'');
console.log(!!0);
console.log(!!5);
```

When we use this notation, the evaluation use the same principle : it tests if the given value is truthy or falsy. In numbers, 1 being truthy, the test checks out, and the `as i` notation simply creates a template variable.

For information, falsy values are `0, '', null, undefined, infinity, NaN`.

Comment: Whoa. That's amazing. I didn't know that. Niceee :) Can you please add some explanation to your post BTW? What exactly are you using here? I haven't seen anything like this before.

Comment: Ok but how to increment it ?

Comment: @MatDepInfo With a `i + 1` in your interpolation. You can try with `i++` and it'll show you why you shouldn't use that !

Comment: @MatDepInfo you should provide a [mcve] of what you expect, random examples like that are always source of mistakes. If you don't know the number of divs, do you at least have some number that says how much divs you have ?

Comment: @MatDepInfo You don't use increments in a template. Because at every change detection, Angular will read the increment, and you will see how strange it gets. Why can't you use ngFor ?